# Real commandline client for CloudFormation?

Tags: command-line-interface, aws-cloudformation

Is there a "real" commandline client for AWS CloudFormation that prints the progress (stack events), blocks until the creation is finished/failed and has a proper exit code?

So far I find myself doing "aws cloudformation update-stack [...]" and then switching to the web interface, reading the Stack events.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid not, afaik.  : (

I was looking for something similar, and from the only thing that I found in the Amazon documentation I concluded that you would need to implement this functionality yourself, i.e. manually print them out using [aws cloudformation describe-stack-events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/describe-stack-events.html)  every so often.

I guess the only way to implement a similar functionality as you get in the web, would be to keep track of what you've already printed out and not print it again the next time you invoke the same command...

Comment: Looks like your're right. Maybe a simple CLI based on botocore would be possible. I wonder how other people use CF when it is so hard to know if your action was successful or not.

Comment: yeah i know... For my part (and for now), I just switch to the web, just like you... 

Soon, I am hoping to look into terraform ( [see here](https://www.terraform.io/intro/vs/cloudformation.html) ) or [chef provisioning](https://github.com/chef/chef-provisioning), so that I can hopefully abstract above CF... Hoping the problem is solved there...

Comment: Well, I think that chef and CF merely work hand in hand than replace each other, but everybody has her own usecase. Terraform is a notable exception of CF abstractions. Most other solutions I found trade "simplicity" for "documented" which doesn't pay off if you work together with many developers... Well, YAML instead if JSON is a must for CF.